# STOMP Protocol - Session ID Questions

Tags: stomp

From the [STOMP 1.0 protocol description](https://stomp.github.io/stomp-specification-1.0.html) (emphasis mine):

> After the client sends the CONNECT
> frame, the server will always
> acknowledge the **connection** by sending
> a frame which looks like:
>
> ```
> CONNECTED
> session: <session-id>
>
> ^@
> ```
>
> session-id header is a unique
> identifier for this **session** (though it
> isn't actually used yet).

Questions:

1. I would assume that the `session-id` value returned after connecting is unique for each connection between a STOMP client and broker. However, since the above description uses the separate terms "connection" and "session", this isn't necessarily the case. Is there any documentation to explain the relationship between `session-id` and connections to the server or can someone confirm my assumption?
2. Is there any documentation available for the format of the session-id value?

My Google searching for answers to these questions didn't reveal any useful information.  I also tried looking at the source code for ActiveMQ 5.4.2 (the broker I'm using), but didn't find any obvious information there either.

Although Question 1 is probably splitting hairs, I'm planning to use the session-id value for a customer's product and would really prefer to *know* rather than *assume* how STOMP behaves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session and Connection are being treated equally.  The session-id header that ActiveMQ gives you will be a globally unique id every time you connect.

Comment: Hiram, Great. Thanks for your reply.  -John